# Does XamlWriter exist in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to write out an object in Silverlight (2) as Xaml. http://www.codeplex.com/silverlightcontrib won't work for me because it's not a FrameworkElement that I'm dealing with. Does anyone know if XamlWriter exists in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not in current version of SL3 and it seems that it won't make it to the final version either.

Answer (score 2):

It's still not in Silverlight 4 either.

Comment: Just checked, not in 5 either :(

Answer (score 1):

This might be a useful substitute for serializing to Xaml however:
http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/

Comment: Since silverlightcontrib went dark 2 years ago..  David Poll's implementation has been the best resource i have found on a Silverlight XAML Writer.

Comment: hoping SL5 SP1 will provide us with this!